# breaking ties in dataframe (dplyr, data.table, base r)

Tags: r, sorting, data.table, dplyr

Thanks for the response thus far.

I've spent a few more hours on my problem and think it's best to reframe my question. I no longer think that dplyr would work.  Here is my issue.

Constrain: require to access column name programmatically (use of dplyr creates problems).

Preferred, but not essential: solution without dataframe copy.

Code set up:

```
set.seed(11)
N <- 12
A <- sample(LETTERS, N, replace=FALSE)
B <- c( rep(c("AA"), 4), rep(c("BA"), 4),rep(c("CA"), 4))
C <- sample(4:10, N, replace=TRUE)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(A,B,C))
dt <- as.data.table(df)

rank_tb <- dt[order(B,C,A)]
```

output:

```
    A B  C
1:  E AA 4
2:  M AA 5
3:  B AA 6
4:  O AA 7
5:  I BA 5
6:  D BA 6
7:  P BA 7
8:  U BA 9
9:  Q CA 5
10: V CA 5
11: J CA 8
12: X CA 9
```

rank_tb gets me half way there, Note grouping on column "B" is preserved, dataframe is then sorted on column "C" by group and finally ties are broken by column "A" -> see row 9 and 10. What I would like, in the end, is the following addition:

```
    A B  C rank
1:  E AA 4 1
2:  M AA 5 2
3:  B AA 6 3
4:  O AA 7 4
5:  I BA 5 1
6:  D BA 6 2
7:  P BA 7 3
8:  U BA 9 4
9:  Q CA 5 1
10: V CA 5 2
11: J CA 8 3
12: X CA 9 4
```

which is a ranked column on "C" grouped by column "B" ties broken by "A".

Below is text of my original question, thanks again for your time..

Is there a method of using a second column to break ties from any of the sort functions like row_number in the dplyr package? At present I have:

```
dat <- data %>% 
filter(!is.na(col1)) %>%
group_by(col2) %>%
filter(row_number(col1) == 1)
```

At present I am unsure how row_number breaks ties in col1, and would like to specify a separate col to use to break the ties:

```
dat <- data %>% 
filter(!is.na(col1)) %>%
group_by(col2) %>%
filter(row_number(col1, col3) == 1)
```

Thanks in adavance

Comment: Did you look at the `?row_number` help page? That function only takes one parameter so if you want to change the order of rows, you'll probably want to `arrange()` (sort) your groups first.

Comment: You want only the first row of each group?

Comment: Please consider to provide a reproducible example with few lines of your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually not quite sure if I understand your question. If you want the first row of each group, you can use

```
data %>% 
group_by(col2) %>%
filter(row_number()==1)
```

Comment: I would rather use `slice(1)` in that case.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up `slice`. However, note that `slice` may not work with databases.